# Changing the size of tableview programmatically

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have created a table view like this

```
@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController{

}
```

Now i want to change the origin & size of the tableview before displaying.

How can i change it ?

Edit :

```
- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    self.tableView.frame=CGRectMake(50, 210, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    return self;
}
```

The problem now i am facing is i have set following code .Now the table view still showing from top position of my view controller(0,0) not according to my x,y position.But if i change the style to group or plain it is only happening properly .

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you have created a new `tableView` instead of trying to move your existing one which InterfaceBuilder created for you.  But since you have not added the new `tableView` to the view hierarchy you cannot see the new one, and you haven't removed the original one...

Instead, just move the original tableView.  In your `rootViewController`'s `viewWillAppear:` method, do the following:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 310, self.view.frame.size.width,200);
}
```

Comment: Something in the superclass implementation is changing the tableView's frame after the viewDidLoad method.  You'll have to set it in viewWillAppear instead.  I've changed the answer accordingly - please try this and accept the answer if it works.

Comment: Still no success, currently i am using MGSplitViewController framework  and i am trying to change the position of x,y cordinate of left panel table view screen and i am testing it in iOS5 simulator.

Comment: You need to start logging your methods to make sure that your classes are setup properly, outlets connected etc...  If you place `NSLog(@"View will appear: view:%@ controller: %@", self.view, self)` in the `viewWillAppear` method above, what does the console say?

Answer (score 3):

you may just get the property **tableView ** to do this

```
tableView.frame = xxxxxx;
```

but i think you just need a UIViewController contains a UITableView

```
UITableView tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:(**the size you want**)];
[self.view addSubView:tableView];
```

Comment: The problem i am facing is i have set following code     self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 310, self.view.frame.size.width,200) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped]; Now the table view still showing from top position of my view controller(0,0) not according to my x,y position.But if i change the   style to group or plain it is only happening properly

Comment: i think you can take 2nd way, use a UIViewController contains a UITableView, it's no difference

Answer (score 1):

If your using StoryBoard and if you have constraints set up. The reloadData will reset whatever you set the frame to. Instead, you should be modifying the constraints. You can do this by creating an outlet and then changing the constant. For instance, below I linked the constraint variable to the top constraint and by setting the constant to -60, it moves it up.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *tableConstraint;

_tableConstraint.constant = -60.;
```