# How to resizing tableview on viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a viewcontroller where I added a tableview into it using the storyboard. The rows are displaying labels of search filters where user tap on the row and a picker will appear at the bottom of the view. I have about 10 rows so when user taps on the last few rows, the data picker blocks of the row. How do I resize the table (made an IBoutlet and called it myTable) and show the selected row above the data picker?

I tried putting this on the 'didSelectRowAtIndexPath' section but not working

```
[self.view addSubview:self.myTable];

self.myTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 148, 320, 10)];
```

Hope someone can help out on this.

Comment: check here similar question to change height of the table.


   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10211942/changing-the-size-of-tableview-programmatically

Comment: try setting `contentInset` of tableview like `tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 150, 0);` don't change frame

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[self.view addSubview:self.myTable];
self.myTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 148, 320, 10)];

[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

Essentially, your goal is to refresh the table view. If that doesn't work, you could even try:

```
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:YES];
```

or:

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: not working. the data reloading is working fine. I just need to resize the height of the table to make it shorter.

Comment: @dan Why aren't you changing the frame then? It just appears as you're alloc and initing it every time instead.

Comment: By the way, I meant to put the reloadRowsAtIndexPaths in between begin and endUpdates.